# Ранжирование числе С и ДО определенного значения

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Есть 2 переменные года начала производства и года окончания:

```
$year_min = 1984
$year_max = 2016
```

Как сделать ражирование с шагом 1 год. Т.е., чтобы было 1984, 1985, 1986....2016?

Comment: эм... `for` ? Или что-то сложнее?

Comment: вроде же `for` достаточно.

Comment: `$year_min = 1984;
$year_max = 2016;
 
for ($i = 0; $i <= ($year_max - $year_min); ++$i) {
 echo ($year_min + $i).'<br />';
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

```
<?php
  $year_min = 1984;
  $year_max = 2016;
  //$step = 1;
  $a = range($year_min, $year_max/*, $step*/);
```